# Messy Urls When Using Regex

Tags: django, django-urls

Im using django allauth and originally users could visit their profiles by visiting `website/profile`, the urls.py being `path('profile/', include('users.urls'))`. I later decided that I want users to view other users profiles so figured Id need to change the urls.py to `path(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>[\w-]+)/$', include('users.urls'))`.

The thing is, now when a user visits a profile, instead of a nice, clean url like `website/profile/user1` it's something like this `website/%5Eprofile/(%3FP1%5B%5Cw-%5D+)/$`.

This may not be a problem, but id prefer a clean url in the address bar of my website, and think it may a sign that my implementation is incorrect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is `%5E` urlencoded and so on with rest of extra characters you have,

You are confusing the old regex path ( [`url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#url) or [`re_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path) ) with new [`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path) syntax

if you want to keep path:

```
path('profile/<username>', include('users.urls'))
```

Also you can check [path converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) if you need custom one

or

```
re_path(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>[\w-]+)/$', include('users.urls'))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### use re_path or slug pattern

```
re_path(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>[\w-]+)/$', include('users.urls'))
#or
path('profile/<slug:user_id>/', include('users.urls'))
```

Comment: it is almost correct but you should not have start and end char of regex in regular path syntax